# using p5js with javascript my function to move works when sent a string but not when sent a variable containing a string

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Using the library known as p5 with javascript i'm trying to make the game snake but it's simply not working. as described in the title it only moves when I give the move function an argument such as "DOWN", but not when I give it the variable direction containing the value "DOWN".

```
let fr = 5

function setup() {
  frameRate(fr)
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

x1 = 201
y1 = 201
direction = "NONE"

function move(direction) {
  if (direction === "UP") {
    y1 = y1 - 20
  }
  else if (direction === "DOWN") {
    y1 = y1 + 20
  }
  else if (direction === "LEFT") {
    x1 = x1 - 20
  }
  else if (direction === "RIGHT") {
    x1 = x1 + 20
  }
}

function draw() {
  let c = color('#1cb82e')
  direction = "down"
  background(0);
  square(x1,y1,18);
    fill(c);
  move(direction);
}

function keyPressed() {
  var validKeys = [37,38,39,40]
  var dict = {
    37:"LEFT",
    38:"UP",
    39:"RIGHT",
    40:"DOWN"
  }
  if (validKeys.includes(keyCode) === true) {
    direction = dict[keyCode];
  }
  print(dict[keyCode])
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? thanks!!
Edit: in case anyone else wants to use the web editor here's the link https://editor.p5js.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your global `direction` variable, and not take any arguments in your `move` function:

```
let fr = 5

function setup() {
  frameRate(fr)
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

x1 = 201
y1 = 201
direction = "NONE"

function move() {
  if (direction === "UP") {
    y1 = y1 - 20
  }
  else if (direction === "DOWN") {
    y1 = y1 + 20
  }
  else if (direction === "LEFT") {
    x1 = x1 - 20
  }
  else if (direction === "RIGHT") {
    x1 = x1 + 20
  }
}

function draw() {
  let c = color('#1cb82e')
  background(0);
  square(x1,y1,18);
    fill(c);
  move();
}

function keyPressed() {
  var validKeys = [37,38,39,40]
  var dict = {
    37:"LEFT",
    38:"UP",
    39:"RIGHT",
    40:"DOWN"
  }
  if (validKeys.includes(keyCode) === true) {
    direction = dict[keyCode];
  }
  print(dict[keyCode])
}
```

Comment: Didn't really click in my head that I was using the same name for a variable, the name of the argument inside the function, and the name of the argument inputted into the function. (direction) I've since tried removing that last line you referenced and renaming the argument inside the function from direction to direction1. sadly it still isn't working :/

Comment: @David I've updated my answer with some code that I think will work right away.

Comment: Surprisingly it still didn't work :/ although it was a nice optimization, i think the issue is with the library itself. When I chose to call move() in the keypressed function at the end it moves once, but still doesn't work in draw() even when I try to call it manually.

Comment: @David are you sure there aren't any other problems? I just copied this code and pasted it [here](https://editor.p5js.org/) and it works fine.

Comment: well it seems while trying to debug it I had a line I accidentally slipped into draw() that constantly set direction to down() but that wasn't there before, so I think your edit fixed it. Thanks for the help :)